# Margin/padding in GridBagLayout Java

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

1. Is it possible to set an margin/padding in `GridBagLayout` for the whole row/column? I use the inset on the constraints-object however, using this approach I need to set padding from bottom on every single component.
2. Is it possible to pad all of the content in the `JFrame`? Because now every component is aligned with the frame.

```
  constraints.weightx = 2;
  constraints.weighty = 1;
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  addComponent(this, layout, constraints, questionPanel = new QuestionPanel(), 0, 0, 1, 1);

  constraints.weightx = 1;
  constraints.weighty = 1;
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  addComponent(this, layout, constraints, categoryPanel = new CategoryPanel(), 0, 1, 1, 1);

  constraints.weightx = 1;
  constraints.weighty = 0;
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  addComponent(this, layout, constraints, answerPanel = new AnswerPanel(), 1, 0, 2, 1);

  constraints.weightx = 1;
  constraints.weighty = 2;
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  addComponent(this, layout, constraints, tabPane = new JTabbedPane(), 2, 0, 2, 1);

  constraints.weightx = 1;
  constraints.weighty = 0;
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
  constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
  addComponent(this, layout, constraints, buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(), 3, 1, 1, 1);
```

I am using a private method addComponent:

```
private void addComponent(Container context, GridBagLayout _layout, GridBagConstraints            _constraints, Component component, int row, int column, int width, int height) {
  _constraints.gridx = column;
  _constraints.gridy = row;
  _constraints.gridwidth = width;
  _constraints.gridheight = height;

  _layout.setConstraints(component, _constraints);
  context.add(component);
 }
```

How can I add some "air(padding/margin)" between the cells?

Comment: I'd say yes and yes... However, without lookint at some code, it is hard to tell for sure. Could you post a snippet?. It would help a lot, your questions are very generic.

Comment: Downvote because there are two questions there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way of doing the first one *is* to set an Insets object for each constraint... (Hand-coding layout clearly wasn't designed to be easy in Java :P )

But there's a very simple way of doing the second, without messing around with any Insets or anything: set the layout of the contentPane to a FlowLayout with whatever vertical and horizontal gaps you want, add a panel to the contentPane, and instead of adding everything to the contentPane, add it to your new panel.

Answer (score 53):

Use the `insets` property of the `GridBagConstraints` class

For example:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.